# OR-Mapping Across Tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, inner-join

I'm sure different ORM tools address the problem differently, but being brand new to the very *concept* of or-mapping, I'm not really concerned with a specific implementation as I am a generic solution. If its simply not possible to answer this question without a specific ORM framework, lets go with Hibernate.

I understand the basic premise of or-mapping, however I'm curious as to how these frameworks handle queries that span multiple tables, such as what occurs when `JOIN`s are present in the query.

```
SELECT f.fizz_name, b.buzz_foo
FROM fizz f
INNER JOIN buzz b
ON f.buzz_id = b.buzz_id
WHERE b.buzz_bar < 10
```

Now we're not getting a nice, clean, single POJO back from the or-mapper. I'm wondering if this is an area where or-mapping breaks down and straight-up JDBC is all a programmer has to work with.

I honestly gave this one a go by myself and couldn't find anything in the Hibernate docs that indicated what happens in this kind of situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give it a go again, this time with feeling: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, different ORM tools probably approach it differently, but in hibernate, you get a List of arrays back, where each column is an object in an Object[].

[See section 16.6 here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) for more explanation.

The key point is you don't need to use plain sql to get results from a join query, at least with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Most ORM frameworks that I'm familiar with *will* allow you to map arbitrary fields from different tables onto a single code object. If you find yourself needing to do this, however, you should *immediately* ask yourself *why* you have data scattered across your database when the code indicates it makes logical sense to be together.

In *almost all* cases where this happens, either the code representation of the object is too large and needs to be broken into it's constituent parts, or the DB representation of the object is to fragmented and the data is much more correlated than the DB indicates.

The specifics of how it is handled differ from ORM to ORM, but hibernate has a number of different ways to handle this, including specifying a specific query in the mapping for a field.

Answer (score 0):

The question might eventually lead deep into discussions about the [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). To avoid that discussion, you should ask yourself whether you're designing an [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) or an [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP) application.

- OLTP: Your JPA entities mostly map directly to the underlying tables, and you can easily perform CRUD operations on them, reading, deleting, storing them. Joins can be seen as pointed out by [hvgotcodes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901478/or-mapping-across-tables/8901601#8901578), as a mere tool of correlating data from various entities for creating predicates, but usually you don't create new ad-hoc types with custom projections. Then, Hibernate is perfect for you.
- OLAP: Your JPA entities hardly map to any underlying tables as the types you want to create using custom projections (`SELECT f.fizz_name, b.buzz_foo`) can be any arbitrary combination of columns / functions / aggregations. This has nothing to do with the joining itself, but with the fact that you create arbitrary projections.

Your example is still quite simple and Hibernate can handle it well, as pointed out by [ChssPly76](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select). In order to get the POJO you want, you can do something like this (from the docs):

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
from DomesticCat as mother
    join mother.mate as mate
    left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

But if you move deeper down into OLAP, you may find Hibernate (HQL, JPQL) not expressive enough. That's where JDBC, [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/), [Spring Templates](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) might be better suited.